# Laravel 9 - display issues on the frontend

Tags: javascript, php, css, mysql, laravel

I'm having issues with the displaying the menus on my front-page, the menus are displaying correctly on other pages but throwing errors on the homepage

I'm having issues with the displaying the menus on my front-page, the menus are displaying correctly on other pages but throwing errors on the homepage

Below are the codes

Please, anyone should kindly help

```js
<x-guest-layout>
    <div
      class="container max-w-lg px-4 py-32 mx-auto text-left bg-center bg-no-repeat bg-cover md:max-w-none md:text-center"
      style="background-image: url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/1396122/pexels-photo-1396122.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500')">
      <h1
        class="font-mono text-3xl font-extrabold text-transparent bg-clip-text bg-gradient-to-r from-green-400 to-blue-500 md:text-center sm:leading-none lg:text-5xl">
        <span class="inline md:block">Welcome To Rentsng</span>
      </h1>
      <div class="mx-auto mt-2 text-red-500 md:text-center lg:text-lg">
        We give the best in real estate management in Nigeria
      </div>
      <div class="flex flex-col items-center mt-12 text-center">
        <span class="relative inline-flex w-full md:w-auto">
          <a href="{{ route('reservations.step.one')}}" type="button"
            class="inline-flex items-center justify-center px-6 py-2 text-base font-bold leading-6 text-white bg-green-600 rounded-full lg:w-full md:w-auto hover:bg-green-500 focus:outline-none">
            Make your reservation
          </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- End Main Hero Content -->
    <section class="px-2 py-32 bg-white md:px-0">
      <div class="container items-center max-w-6xl px-8 mx-auto xl:px-5">
        <div class="flex flex-wrap items-center sm:-mx-3">
          <div class="w-full md:w-1/2 md:px-3">
            <div class="w-full pb-6 space-y-4 sm:max-w-md lg:max-w-lg lg:space-y-4 lg:pr-0 md:pb-0">
              <!-- <h1
              class="text-4xl font-extrabold tracking-tight text-gray-900 sm:text-5xl md:text-4xl lg:text-5xl xl:text-6xl"
            > -->
              <h3 class="text-xl">OUR STORY
              </h3>
              <h2 class="text-4xl text-green-600">Welcome</h2>
              <!-- </h1> -->
              <p class="mx-auto text-base text-gray-500 sm:max-w-md lg:text-xl md:max-w-3xl">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Temporibus nemo incidunt praesentium, ipsum
                culpa minus eveniet, id nesciunt excepturi sit voluptate repudiandae. Explicabo, incidunt quia.
                Repellendus mollitia quaerat est voluptas!
              </p>
              <div class="relative flex">
                <a href="#_"
                  class="flex items-center w-full px-6 py-3 mb-3 text-lg text-white bg-green-600 rounded-md sm:mb-0 hover:bg-green-700 sm:w-auto">
                  Read More
                  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="w-5 h-5 ml-1" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none"
                    stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round">
                    <line x1="5" y1="12" x2="19" y2="12"></line>
                    <polyline points="12 5 19 12 12 19"></polyline>
                  </svg>
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="w-full md:w-1/2">
            <div class="w-full h-auto overflow-hidden rounded-md shadow-xl sm:rounded-xl">
              <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/08/03/13/30/people-2576336_960_720.jpg" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section class="py-20 bg-gray-50">
      <div class="container items-center max-w-6xl px-4 px-10 mx-auto sm:px-20 md:px-32 lg:px-16">
        <div class="flex flex-wrap items-center -mx-3">
          <div class="order-1 w-full px-3 lg:w-1/2 lg:order-0">
            <div class="w-full lg:max-w-md">
              <h2 class="mb-4 text-2xl font-bold">About Us</h2>
              <h2
                class="mb-4 text-3xl font-bold text-transparent bg-clip-text bg-gradient-to-r from-green-400 to-blue-500">
                WHY CHOOSE US?</h2>

              <p class="mb-4 font-medium tracking-tight text-gray-400 xl:mb-6">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur
                adipisicing elit. Natus hic atque magni minus aliquam, eos quam incidunt nam iusto sunt voluptates
                inventore a veritatis doloremque corrupti. Veritatis est expedita cupiditate!</p>
              <ul>
                <li class="flex items-center py-2 space-x-4 xl:py-3">
                  <svg class="w-8 h-8 text-gray-500" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                    <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2"
                      d="M9 3v2m6-2v2M9 19v2m6-2v2M5 9H3m2 6H3m18-6h-2m2 6h-2M7 19h10a2 2 0 002-2V7a2 2 0 00-2-2H7a2 2 0 00-2 2v10a2 2 0 002 2zM9 9h6v6H9V9z">
                    </path>
                  </svg>
                  <span class="font-medium text-gray-500">Faster Processing and Delivery</span>
                </li>
                <li class="flex items-center py-2 space-x-4 xl:py-3">
                  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="w-8 h-8 text-gray-500" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                    stroke="currentColor">
                    <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2"
                      d="M12 8c-1.657 0-3 .895-3 2s1.343 2 3 2 3 .895 3 2-1.343 2-3 2m0-8c1.11 0 2.08.402 2.599 1M12 8V7m0 1v8m0 0v1m0-1c-1.11 0-2.08-.402-2.599-1M21 12a9 9 0 11-18 0 9 9 0 0118 0z" />
                  </svg>
                  <span class="font-medium text-gray-500">Easy Payments</span>
                </li>
                <li class="flex items-center py-2 space-x-4 xl:py-3">
                  <svg class="w-8 h-8 text-gray-500" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                    <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2"
                      d="M9 12l2 2 4-4m5.618-4.016A11.955 11.955 0 0112 2.944a11.955 11.955 0 01-8.618 3.04A12.02 12.02 0 003 9c0 5.591 3.824 10.29 9 11.622 5.176-1.332 9-6.03 9-11.622 0-1.042-.133-2.052-.382-3.016z">
                    </path>
                  </svg>
                  <span class="font-medium text-gray-500">100% Protection and Security for Your App</span>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="w-full px-3 mb-12 lg:w-1/2 order-0 lg:order-1 lg:mb-0"><img
              class="mx-auto sm:max-w-sm lg:max-w-full"
              src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/12/31/12/28/cook-5876388_960_720.png" alt="feature image"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section class="mt-8 bg-white">
      <div class="mt-4 text-center">
        <h3 class="text-2xl font-bold">Our Menu</h3>
        <h2 class="text-3xl font-bold text-transparent bg-clip-text bg-gradient-to-r from-green-400 to-blue-500">
          TODAY'S SPECIALITY</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="container w-full px-5 py-6 mx-auto">
        <div class="grid lg:grid-cols-4 gap-y-6">

            @foreach ($specials->menus as $menu)

          <div class="max-w-xs mx-4 mb-2 rounded-lg shadow-lg">
            <img class="w-full h-48" src="{{ Storage::url($menu->image)}}"
              alt="Image" />
            <div class="px-6 py-4">

              <h4 class="mb-3 text-xl font-semibold tracking-tight text-green-600 uppercase">{{ $menu->name}}</h4>
              <p class="leading-normal text-gray-700">{{ $menu->description}}</p>
            </div>
            <div class="flex items-center justify-between p-4">

              <span class="text-xl text-green-600">{{ $menu->price}}</span>
            </div>
          </div>

          @endforeach

        </div>
      </div>
    </section>

    <section class="pt-4 pb-12 bg-gray-800">
      <div class="my-16 text-center">
        <h2 class="text-3xl font-bold text-transparent bg-clip-text bg-gradient-to-r from-green-400 to-blue-500">
          Testimonial </h2>
        <p class="text-xl text-white">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. soluta sapient</p>
      </div>
      <div class="grid gap-2 lg:grid-cols-3">
        <div class="max-w-md p-4 bg-white rounded-lg shadow-lg">
          <div class="flex justify-center -mt-16 md:justify-end">
            <img class="object-cover w-20 h-20 border-2 border-green-500 rounded-full"
              src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1499714608240-22fc6ad53fb2?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=334&q=80">
          </div>
          <div>
            <h2 class="text-3xl font-semibold text-gray-800">Food</h2>
            <p class="mt-2 text-gray-600">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quae dolores deserunt
              ea doloremque natus error, rerum quas odio quaerat nam ex commodi hic, suscipit in a veritatis pariatur
              minus consequuntur!</p>
          </div>
          <div class="flex justify-end mt-4">
            <a href="#" class="text-xl font-medium text-green-500">John Doe</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="max-w-md p-4 bg-white rounded-lg shadow-lg">
          <div class="flex justify-center -mt-16 md:justify-end">
            <img class="object-cover w-20 h-20 border-2 border-green-500 rounded-full"
              src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/01/04/21/15/young-3061652__340.jpg">
          </div>
          <div>
            <h2 class="text-3xl font-semibold text-gray-800">Food</h2>
            <p class="mt-2 text-gray-600">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quae dolores deserunt
              ea doloremque natus error, rerum quas odio quaerat nam ex commodi hic, suscipit in a veritatis pariatur
              minus consequuntur!</p>
          </div>
          <div class="flex justify-end mt-4">
            <a href="#" class="text-xl font-medium text-green-500">John Doe</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="max-w-md p-4 bg-white rounded-lg shadow-lg">
          <div class="flex justify-center -mt-16 md:justify-end">
            <img class="object-cover w-20 h-20 border-2 border-green-500 rounded-full"
              src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/01/18/17/48/purchase-3090818__340.jpg">
          </div>
          <div>
            <h2 class="text-3xl font-semibold text-gray-800">Food</h2>
            <p class="mt-2 text-gray-600">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quae dolores deserunt
              ea doloremque natus error, rerum quas odio quaerat nam ex commodi hic, suscipit in a veritatis pariatur
              minus consequuntur!</p>
          </div>
          <div class="flex justify-end mt-4">
            <a href="#" class="text-xl font-medium text-green-500">John Doe</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>

    <section class="pt-12 pb-12 bg-red-50">
      <div class="container flex items-center justify-center p-6 mx-auto bg-white shadow-lg sm:p-12 md:w-1/2">
        <div class="w-full">

          <h1
            class="mb-4 text-2xl font-bold text-center text-transparent bg-clip-text bg-gradient-to-r from-green-400 to-blue-500">
            Order Now FREE AND FAST
          </h1>
          <div class="gap-2 mb-8 lg:flex">
            <div class="w-full">
              <label class="block text-base">
                Your Name
              </label>
              <input type="text"
                class="w-full px-4 py-2 text-base border rounded-md focus:border-green-400 focus:outline-none focus:ring-1 focus:ring-green-600"
                placeholder="Your Name" />
            </div>
            <div class="w-full">
              <label class="block text-base">
                Your Number
              </label>
              <input type="text"
                class="w-full px-4 py-2 text-base border rounded-md focus:border-green-400 focus:outline-none focus:ring-1 focus:ring-green-600"
                placeholder="Your Number" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="gap-2 mb-8 lg:flex">
            <div class="w-full">
              <label class="block text-base">
                Table Number
              </label>
              <input type="text"
                class="w-full px-4 py-2 text-base border rounded-md focus:border-green-400 focus:outline-none focus:ring-1 focus:ring-green-600"
                placeholder="Enter Table Number 1 to 12" />
            </div>
            <div class="w-full">
              <label class="block text-base">
                Booking Date
              </label>
              <input type="date"
                class="w-full px-4 py-2 text-base border rounded-md focus:border-green-400 focus:outline-none focus:ring-1 focus:ring-green-600"
                placeholder="Your Number" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="">
            <label class="block text-base">
              Your Message
            </label>
            <textarea name="" id="" rows="4" cols="30"
              class="w-full text-base border rounded-md focus:border-green-400 focus:outline-none focus:ring-1 focus:ring-green-600"
              placeholder="Message"></textarea>
          </div>
          <button
            class="px-4 py-2 mt-4 text-sm font-medium leading-5 text-center text-white transition-colors duration-150 bg-green-600 border border-transparent rounded-lg active:bg-green-600 hover:bg-green-700 focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline-green"
            href="#">
            Book Now
          </button>

        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
</x-guest-layout>
```

[image]y help please

Comment: From the error, it seems ```$special``` is null. need to add the condition to check ```$special```  like ```$special ? $special : ''```

Comment: What's your question about this error? Anything unclear? How is your problem related to CSS, MySQL, or Javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in place of the section with the @foreach loop.
We need an @if statement to determine whether $specials is defined/true or not.

```
<section class="mt-8 bg-white">
  <div class="mt-4 text-center">
    <h3 class="text-2xl font-bold">Our Menu</h3>
    <h2 class="text-3xl font-bold text-transparent bg-clip-text bg-gradient-to-r from-green-400 to-blue-500">
      TODAY'S SPECIALITY</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="container w-full px-5 py-6 mx-auto">
    <div class="grid lg:grid-cols-4 gap-y-6">
      @if ($special ? $special : '')

      @foreach ($specials->menus as $menu)

      <div class="max-w-xs mx-4 mb-2 rounded-lg shadow-lg">
        <img class="w-full h-48" src="{{ Storage::url($menu->image)}}" alt="Image" />
        <div class="px-6 py-4">

          <h4 class="mb-3 text-xl font-semibold tracking-tight text-green-600 uppercase">{{ $menu->name}}</h4>
          <p class="leading-normal text-gray-700">{{ $menu->description}}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="flex items-center justify-between p-4">

          <span class="text-xl text-green-600">{{ $menu->price}}</span>
        </div>
      </div>

      @endforeach
      @endif

    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```